# Placement of extended partial classes in entity framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, partial-classes

Since partial classes have to be in the same namespace is my only option to place them in the same directy as my .edmx? If this is the case I am assuming the file name always has to be different.

Also, is there anything additional that I have to do or do I just create another partial class with the same name in the same directory and add properties/methods to it?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The partial classes should be in the same project as the .edmx-file. (the same directory is not required).

Say your Entity Model contains an Entity Person. You can create a new file called `Person.partial.cs` for your other code. You are free to use any filename for your partial classes. It is only necessary that your partial class is defined in the namespace of the Entity.

```
namespace MyModel{
   public partial class Person {
      // put your additional logic here
   } 
}
```